# RXJS BehaviourSubject emmission order change with combineLatest

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject, combinelatest

In an Angular application, I'm **modeling "state" with a BehaviourSubject**.

```
interface State {
  id: number;
  num: number;
  msg: string;
}
private store = new BehaviorSubject<State>(_state);
private state$ = this.store.asObservable();
```

And I got observables to select the different **slices of state**:

```
  msg$ = this.state$.pipe(
   map((state) => state.msg),
   distinctUntilChanged()
  );

  id$ = this.state$.pipe(
   map((state) => state.id),
   distinctUntilChanged()
  );

 num$ = this.state$.pipe(
   map((state) => state.num),
  distinctUntilChanged()
 );
```

I initialize the state, then **update** its value using **this.store.next** with data from an API. Everything is fine until that point.

But I'm also using **combineLatest** to wait for the emission on two of the observables that slice the state (id and num), to **calculate a value** for the third one (msg).

So I emmit to the state id and num, and then inside the combineLatest I calculate and emmit to the state a new msg.

The problem is that in the component subscribed to the "msg" observable **I receive the correct calculated value**, but **after I receive the old (the initial) value**. Is like combineLatest interrupts the emission in the observables with the correct value, but then the old ones resume and are the latest to be received. Why the order is changing?

I created this [example in StackBlizt](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yx6pmn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstore.service.ts) to check problem.

I expect to have at Message "Data 1 123", but I see the initial value "hi".

Maybe someone knows what it's happening and how to fix it?

Comment: please include a complete sample into the post - including only this part end rest on stackblitz is inconvenient.

Comment: just a note - behavior subject already has a way to access current value = .getValue() or simply .value - then you dont need to store the value as _value

Comment: Thanks @kvetis for the comments, I tried to put a summarized version thinking it was clearer, good tip for next time, the getValue is useful too, I will change it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [article](https://blog.strongbrew.io/combine-latest-glitch/) helped me to find a solution. Putting a **debounceTime(0)** first thing in the **combineLatest** it seems put it out of the event loop and allows execution in the expected order. I update also the [StackBlizt example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yx6pmn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstore.service.ts) with the solution in the case that is useful for someone with a similar problem.